# Time complexity of a program javascript to schedule tasks

Tags: javascript, queue, scheduler, round-robin

Your research facility just received a new supercomputer. It is capable of working on several different tasks at once, but only if it knows how long each task will take to give a result.

This supercomputer measures time in time units and operates in the following way:

All tasks that need to be processed are placed in the queue.
The task at the top of the queue is given exactly 1 time unit of CPU time. If it’s not completed it’s placed at the back of the queue.
Task rescheduling in the queue is managed by a special processing unit and as such takes no additional CPU time.
You’ve submitted your task to the processing queue and you want to find out how long you need to wait until the results are ready.

Given the taskQueue as an array of positive integers, where taskQueue[i] represents the number of time units of CPU time left for the ith task in the queue to give results and a positive integer n as a current index of your task in the taskQueue (0-based), find the number of time units you’ll need to wait until your task is completed.

Example

For taskQueue = [3, 1, 2] and n = 2, the output should be
multitasking(taskQueue, n) = 5.
If we go through the queue states with 1 time unit steps it’ll look like:
[3, 1, 2'] -> [1, 2', 2] -> [2', 2] -> [2, 1'] -> [1', 1] -> [1]
where your task is marked with ’.
For taskQueue = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2] and n = 0, the output should be
multitasking(taskQueue, n) = 1.
Input/Output

[time limit] 4000ms (js)
[input] array.integer taskQueue

The ith integer represents the number of time units of CPU time left for the ith task in the queue to give results.

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ taskQueue.length ≤ 105
1 ≤ taskQueue[i] ≤ 109.

[input] integer n

The index of your task in the taskQueue (0-based).

Guaranteed constraints:
0 ≤ n < taskQueue.length.

[output] integer64

The number of time units you need to wait until your task is completed.

This is the code I have written:

```
function multitasking(taskQueue, n) {
let queue = new Queue(taskQueue,n);
while(queue.data.length) {
    queue.runTask();
}
return queue.count;
```

}

```
function Queue(data,n) {
this.data = [...data];
this.taskIndex = n;
this.count = 0;

this.requeue = function() {
    let firstvalue = this.data[0];        
    if(this.taskIndex) {
        this.taskIndex--;
    } else if(!firstvalue) {
        this.data = [];      
        return;                              
    } else {
        this.taskIndex = this.data.length-1;
    }
    if(firstvalue) {
        this.data.push(firstvalue);
    }
    this.data.shift();
} 

this.runTask = function() {
    this.data[0]--;
    this.count++;
    this.requeue();
}}
```

This works well for most cases. But the time complexity is high. for. eg.

multitasking([1000000000,1000000000],1) this doesn't solve under 4000ms. Can anyone help me reduce the time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running a simulation instead of an analysis. This is based on adjusting `queue.count` by one using an increment operator. The time taken to calculate time remaining will increase depending on how long the task will take to complete.

My first thoughts on analysing  time remaining without going through each step were as follows (untested, uncoded):

1. Normalize the task queue to put the nth zero based task at the head.
   this will take (n) units of time, so set total time to (n). Do not add tasks preceding your task which had a time remaining of 1 to the end of the normalized queue.
2. find the least time required count in following tasks that is less than what your task requires.
3. If a task was found in step 2, add its time, multiplied by the task queue length, to the total time, and subtract the task time from all times in the queue. Remove the task found from the queue.
4. If at any time the time remaining for your task is one, add one to the total and return it.
5. if a task was found in step 2, repeat from step 2.
6. Add the time remaining for your task to finish to the total and return the result.

---

Update:

Second thoughts would be to still "normalize" the queue - what would the queue look like after `n` time units, where `n` is the position of the task in the queue (it may be zero)?

Now the question arises, does the order of executing other tasks in the queue in round robin fashion affect calculating time  for your task to complete? If not you could sort the remainder of the queue into, say, descending order while leaving your task at the top of the queue.

If order doesn't matter, you could process sorted queue entries staring from the end of the array,  and by maintaining more than one accumulator (e.g. total time taken and counts of queue iterations required) calculate the time needed for your task to complete without ever manipulating the array structure of the queue, or even entry values in the array.

Finer details still need to be handled, but the time taken to perform this kind of analysis should depend on the length of the initial queue rather than the time remaining for each task.